# Looking for an analythic funtion

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

Given is the function $g(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}F(\frac{Cx^2}{y})$, where $C$=const and $F$ is an arbitrary function. Can you give examples of $F$ such that $g(x,y)$ is analytic (or at least smooth) when $y=0$ $\forall x$.

Attempt at solution:

Try $g(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}e^{-\frac{Cx^2}{y}}$. It is well defined at $y\rightarrow0$ if $x \ne 0$. However, it is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Try $g(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{Cy}{x^2})}$. We have $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} g(x,y) \rightarrow \frac{x^3}{C}$. I did plot $g(x,y)$ in this case and it is still discontinuous at $x=0$.

Is there a function that will work?

Comment: What about $F=0?$

Comment: I was wondering if I am missing a nonzero function that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $c \ne 0$, 
$$ g(x, c x^2) = \frac{1}{c x} F(C/c)$$
Unless $F = 0$, this will be always be discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: It is discontinued along the parabola $y=cx^2$ for any $c\ne0$; no matter the choice of $F$?